# What is git's advertised refs?

Tags: git, jgit

There is a org.eclipse.jgit.transport.OperationResult#getAdvertisedRefs in jgit. The term seems to be not specific to jgit but I can't find any precise description of the advertised refs.

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Transfer Protocols - Downloading Data](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols):

> At this point, the fetch-pack process looks at what objects it has and responds with the objects that it needs by sending "want" and then the SHA it wants. It sends all the objects it already has with "have" and then the SHA.

During a fetch, the server can list references that it has and that the client may wish to fetch. These are the advertised references.